# Integrating Phone Gap in an existing Sencha Touch project

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

I need help integrating **Phone Gap** in an existing and *fully working* [with iOS & Android] **Sencha Touch** project. The reason I need to do this is that I want to be able to use native code [Objective-C] in this application for features like GPS, animations, etc.

*By the way, is there an other way to use native code without Phone Gap?*.

Those are the steps I followed so far:

1. `phonegap add platform ios` & `phonegap add platform android` in the application folder.
   This created a "phonegap" folder in the Sencha Touch project folder.
2. phonegap build ios
   This created the `.xcodeproj` file in the `phonegap/platform/ios/` folder.

What step do I need to do now? How can I create and use native iOS plugins?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/leveraging-phonegap-within-sencha-touch/) from the Sencha blog should answer all of your questions regarding the process to integrate Sencha Touch with PhoneGap (or Cordova).

> By the way, is there an other way to use native code without Phone Gap?

I believe there are other solutions out there, but none are really as widespread as Cordova/PhoneGap. For example, a variety of mobility solutions like [Sencha Space](http://www.sencha.com/products/space/) also exist... but if you're one developer building a single application, the odds are that Cordova/PhoneGap is the best (easiest?) choice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use phonegap directly. So when you got the .xcodeproj file just open it in XCode an build the project. Normally the created xcode project can be run without further modifications.

Answer (score 0):

First consider Phonegap vs Cordova if there is no need to remote build use Cordova (IMO)

That been said :

1.- inside ST project: `sencha cordova init com.mycompany.myappname MyAppName`

2.- inside cordova folder `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git`

3.- validate inside app.js in launch method `alert(device.uuid)`

DONE

Reference: http://vimeo.com/76568053